# Shopware 6.4.13 Console Error when ./bin/console cache:clear

Tags: shopware, shopware6

This is the error I get on a clean Shopware 6.4.13 system when I clear the cache via console.

"User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : Class Shopware\Storefront\Event\ThemeCompilerEnrichScssVariablesEvent is deprecated. Use Shopware\Storefront\Theme\Event\ThemeCompilerEnrichScssVariablesEvent instead."

Any ideas whats going on at the Showpare HQ or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, this is merely [a new strategy](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/adr/workflow/2022-02-28-consistent-deprecation-notices-in-core) to more openly communicate deprecations. If you see this message the [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) of your PHP instance you use in CLI is set to also report "errors" of type `E_DEPRECATED`. You can change that in your `php.ini` to be less verbose.

As @j_elfering already said this is still subject to change but for now you can also add the `--no-debug` option to suppress the deprecation messages:

```bash
bin/console cache:clear --no-debug
```

Answer (score 2):

The message you got is "only" a deprecation message, that does not indicate an error.

The reason is that the event was refactored, but for backwards compatibility currently the old/deprecated event and the new one are both thrown. Starting with shopware 6.5 the deprecated Event will be removed and the message will not appear anymore.